# laravel eloquent where method

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have a courses table I want to query like this :

```
semesters = [5,3,7];

$class_id = 3;

Course::where(['class_id' => $class_id, 'semester_id' => $semesters ])->get();
```

where `$semesters` must be an array. so I want to get the collection of courses where class_id is 3 and where semester_id is 5,3,7. however it gets the collection of only the first index of the $semester array. how do I get the collection of all the values of that $semester array?

Comment: Use `whereIn`: `Course::whereIn('semester_id', $semesters)->where('class_id', $class_id)->get()`

Comment: exactly what I seek for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Use `WhereIn`**

```
Course::whereIn('semester_id', $semesters)->where('semester_id', $semesters)->get();
```

Comment: This exact answer is in my comment above.